# eclipse debug view shows thread instead of variables

Tags: eclipse, debugging

[image: pic of issue]
[image]

as the pic shows, only the variables local to the function are shown and the current thread(humanPlayer)
i havent knowingly changed any settings?
im struggling to debug my code for the last few hours and id love help on how to get this back to normal
this usually opens up the actual object and i can peek inside and see its variables which is how i usually go about debugging
it usually shows everything thats in the current class rather than function

Comment: Does `HumanPlayer` extend `Thread` - that display just looks like the class members you would see for something extending Thread. The `java.Util.Scanner s` at the bottom looks like one of your members.

Comment: it does indeed extend Thread! however it wasnt displaying it like that till awhile ago (this specific class and project)... can i somehow filter out only the class variables?

Comment: I'm not sure. An alternative is to just make your class implement `Runnable` and pass it to a standard `Thread` in the constructor.

Comment: this might fix it but that would go against the assignment